# How to achieve ThreadLocal variable functionality in NodeJS without using req and res.locals?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bookshelf.js

I have a scenario where I need to do some business logic and logging for each request. So the data to be stored should be mutually exclusive with other requests.

I cannot use res.locals or req objects because the processing should start based on an event. And the event callback does not contain these objects.

Its basically saved event of bookshelfjs.

```
initialize: function(){

  this.on("saving",function(model, attrs, options){
    //do some stuff
    //require data from request
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have threads in Node.JS, you have [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).

Some packages to look at therefore are [continuation-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage) and [request-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-local-storage).

You can achieve something similar by (ab)using the [Domain API](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html). Or you can do away with the need for it entirely if you can structure your closures or callback arguments appropriately.